# Uuntu 22.04 on boot - "atom_execute_table_locked "

Tags: boot, 22.04

Then radionbios in loop.
This  slows the computer till it locks up. Published fixes tried to no avail. If i blacklist radion my screen shows distorted texts and images.

Comment: on boot the message Access beyond end of device, and another about the end of range appear, The fly by so quickly i haven't read them accurately. ALSO it takes a real long time to boot to the home screen